# pythion Check number is prime

Tags: python, primes

HELP : 
A prime number is a natural number greater than 1 that cannot be formed by multiplying two smaller natural numbers. For Example, 5 prime .8 is not prime because it has list of [1,2,4,8]as its divisors. Implement The function isPrime() which determines if a number is prime or not.
- The parameter of this function are num(int) and(list).We Assume that number is an integer greater than 1 and L is an empty list.This Assumption Does Not Need To Be Checked.
-The function returns True if num is prime and return False otherwise
-If Num Is Not Prime, the list of divisors of numis assigned L and printed. The list includes 1 and num. When number is prime , L can be any value and is not printed.
def isPrime(num, L):
    # Implement the function here
    # If syntax error occurs, no point will be given for this function
    # Do not change the function header
ans = isPrime(8,[])  # This cell is for your confirmation, can be removed.
print(ans)           # If correctly implemented, [1,2,4,8] is printed first, and False is printed at the

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).
Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a homework question. Anyhow; run

```
for i in range(1, num/2):
 if num % i == 0:
   L.append(i)
```

to get the list of divisors.
Then; if the length of the list (len(L)) is more than 2, return false and print the list, else return true.

Comment: Try `for i in range(2, num/2):` instead.  Checking for divisibility by 1 is a waste of time.